# Parse JSON nested object to Java POJO with GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I would like to parse JSON string with nested array to POJO with Gson but it seems that it does not work.

My JSON string is as follow:

```
{
   "magdeburg":{
      "average":"21.40",
      "maximum":"22.33",
      "minimum":"19.06"
   },
   "frankfurt":{
      "average":"16.41",
      "maximum":"16.57",
      "minimum":"16.09"
   }
}
```

with my POJO class as follow:

```
public class PingResult {

    public double average;
    public double maximum;
    public double minimum;

    public PingResult(double average, double maximum, double minimum) {
        this.average= average;
        this.maximum =  maximum;
        this.minimum= minimum;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "average:" + this.average + ",maximum:"+this.maximum+",minimum:"+this.minimum;
    }
}
```

but when I want to parse it to POJO with the code like this:

```
List<PingResult> pr =  (List<PingResult>) gson.fromJson(q, PingResult.class);
        for(PingResult p:pr) {
            System.out.println(p.toString());
        }
```

it gave error of

> java.lang.ClassCastException: PingResult cannot be cast to
>   java.util.List    at
>   DelayBasedMeasurement.main(DelayBasedMeasurement.java:380).

I have tried to parse to PingResult[] but still it does not work.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how to do it with a `List`, but this is how to do it with `Map`:

```java
Map<String, Ping> map = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<Map<String, Ping>>(){}.getType());
```

Then you can just `map.values()` if you want all the values.

Answer (score 1):

First, `gson.fromJson(q, PingResult.class)` won't return a List, only a single object. You need to use a `TypeToken`.

Secondly, you don't have a list of JSON objects, you have a map. There are no `[]` characters, and each ping result is the value of the city string key.

Try  `TreeMap<String, PingResult>` as your deserialization type

```
Type pingType =  new TypeToken<TreeMap<String, PingResult>>(){}.getType();

TreeMap<String, PingResult> pingMap = gson.fromJson(json, pingType);
```